# Could not find jquery-ui-rails-4.2.0.gem for installation

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm stumped with this one.

I've included the gem in my gemfile as

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.2.0'
```

and even as

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

which makes no difference, but still I'm not able to find any version of it. I tried several lower versions, but still - no success. I remember being able to use jquery-ui-rails in my project, but suddenly I cannot anymore!

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I just discovered that I can't add ANY new gem to my gemfile. It always says it cannot find ANY gem

**EDIT**

As soon as I remove a gem, update via `bundle update`, and then add the removed gem again and update via `bundle update` again, it says that the required gem is not found!

Comment: What do you see when you run `$gem install jquery-ui-rails` ?

Comment: That is working, but I want to use the gemfile :S I just discovered that I can't add ANY new gem to my gemfile. It always says it cannot find ANY gem.

Comment: Did you put something like `source 'https://rubygems.org'` at the beginning of your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I tried both `source :rubygems` and `source http://...`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

1. Reinstall bundler
2. Delete Gemfile.lock

solved the problem